# Create a report with its respective chart from a chosen LINQ query in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, datatable

I'm quite busy reading different posts over how to create reports from dynamic queries. I have the next problem and maybe someone here can help me with this:

I have a class where I can create a dataGridView from a dynamic dataTable in a project made with C# from VS 2010. I populate my DataTable with one of 9 different linq queries that I have according to the user requirements, which also are saved in a register in my database. Starting from this point, I need to make a report where I can show of the same way the data selected.

I have found the code from the website [got ReportViewer](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) and it works quite good. Only I have a last problem. I need my report to show a chart according to the parameters passed via the DataTable. I saw the examples that they have there for the charts but they work quite restrict with what I need, and the code for the chart generator that is incluided in the Dynamic Table project is quite extense and a bit complex for a beginner like me.

Do you know any other examples that maybe I can find to use to make the code in my project? Many thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it:

- Now I'm using classes as datasources and filling arrays of these classes with the contect of the datatable.
- I pass these arrays as my datasources for the project.
- I group my data by the number of fields I want to display and then I choose between pre made .rdlc files where I show my data to the user.